# Compiler error on OpenSUSE 13.2 for GCC (OpenSIPS 1.8)

Tags: gcc, opensuse, opensips

Fresh headless install of OpenSUSE 13.2. Installed the development tools using:

```
zypper install -t pattern devel_C_C++
```

Used SVN to checkout the latest 1.8 version of OpenSIPS. I'm trying to get it installed but it's unable to make the menuconfig.

```
which: no xsltproc in     (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games)
which: no lynx in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games)
cd menuconfig; make ; cd ..
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/opensips_1_8/menuconfig'
gcc -o configure -g -Wall -DMENUCONFIG_CFG_PATH=\"menuconfig/configs/\" -    DMENUCONFIG_GEN_PATH=\"etc/\" -DMENUCONFIG_HAVE_SOURCES=1 cfg.o curses.o items.o commands.o     menus.o parser.o main.o -lcurses
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurses
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/opensips_1_8/menuconfig'
./menuconfig/configure --local
make: ./menuconfig/configure: Command not found
Makefile:883: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 127
```

It seems as if it's not the right version of GCC to compile it? I tried with 4.9, but that was worse.

Any help is appreciated.

Update, curses is installed:

linux-9g76:/usr/src/opensips_1_8 # zypper se curses
    Loading repository data...
    Reading installed packages...

```
S | Name                     | Summary                                                   | Type   
--+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------
i | libncurses5              | The New curses Libraries                                      | package
i | libncurses5-32bit        | The New curses Libraries                                      | package
i | libncurses6              | The New curses Libraries                                      | package
i | libncurses6-32bit        | The New curses Libraries                                      | package
  | libyui-ncurses-devel     | Libyui-ncurses header files                               |     package
  | libyui-ncurses-doc       | Libyui-ncurses documentation                              |     package
  | libyui-ncurses-pkg-devel | Libyui-ncurses-pkg header files                           |     package
  | libyui-ncurses-pkg-doc   | Libyui-ncurses-pkg documentation                          | package
i | libyui-ncurses-pkg6      | Libyui - yast2 package selector widget for the ncurses UI | package
i | libyui-ncurses6          | Libyui - Character Based User Interface                   | package
i | ncurses-devel            | Include Files and Libraries mandatory for Development     | package
i | ncurses-devel-32bit      | Include Files and Libraries mandatory for Development     | package
i | ncurses-utils            | Tools using the new curses libraries                      | package
  | perl-Curses              | Terminal screen handling and optimization                 | package
  | perl-CursesWidgets       | CursesWidgets Perl module                                 | package
  | python-curses            | Python Interface to the (N)Curses Library                 | package
  | python3-curses           | Python Interface to the (N)Curses Library                 | package
```

Comment: ‘`cannot find -lcurses`’ Have you installed the curses library?

Comment: Then you should probably provide the linker with its path (`-L`), so that it can find it.

Comment: How do you do this? My experience somewhat stops past make menuconfig. I have no idea how to modify compiler options in the Makefile.

Comment: That's probably a zypper thing, and I know zip about zypper, sorry. What does strike me though is that the list of libraries doesn't really contain one called `curses`.

Comment: I'm still lost. What does -lcurses even mean? Is this a GCC issue, or this a dependency issue? I have no idea what has failed or where to look.

Comment: That information is, naturally, available [in the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-Libraries-1077), but in short it means ‘link with the “curses” library’.

Comment: Well then it's a GCC error with OpenSIPS and way way past my pay grade. The question needs to be moved to them I guess. Does anything ever work in Linux? Sheesh. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: A lot if things work in Linux, and the ones that don't are often fixable. But let's avoid *that* discussion. Have you tried just installing the curses library?

Comment: There's no such thing though. I've been searching for a curses library for OpenSUSE for 15 minutes. All I can find is ncurses, and that's installed via zypper.